# Protecting documents using Labels

Tags: azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

Since File API is not available to mobile platform, is there anyway we can protect documents using Label with UPE framework.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the [MIP SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip) and use [C++/CX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/universal-windows-apps-cpp?view=vs-2019)